# Can't return a boolean to ionViewCanLeave

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have to show my customized alert(designed by modal) when user want to leave current page. It prompt yes or no buttons. If user click yes, I want to return false(ie shouldn't leave the page). If user click no, I want to return true(ie leave the page).

I've tried lots of solutions, but nothing helped me.

```
ionViewCanLeave(): boolean {
if (this.operationMode == undefined) {
  if (this.cycleMode == "AA") {
    if (
      this.oroficeLevel != this.oroficeLevelInitial ||
      this.name != this.nameInitial ||
      this.scheduleMode != this.scheduleModeInitial
    ) {
      let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AlertPage, {
        message: "Save Changes?"
      });
      modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
        if (data == "yes") {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
      modal.present();
    }
  } else if (this.cycleMode == "CC") {
    if (
      this.oroficeLevel != this.oroficeLevelInitial ||
      this.name != this.nameInitial ||
      this.scheduleMode != this.scheduleModeInitial
    ) {
      let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AlertPage, {
        message: "Save Changes?"
      });
      modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
        if (data == "yes") {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
      modal.present();
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong with this code ?

Comment: @Random, the return statement is inside of the modal dismiss handler. So it is not the scope of a ionViewCanLeave()

Comment: I don't know ionic, but some times you can provide a promise instead of a boolean in such methods. Have a look at the modal doc if there is a method which return the "exit" promise... If so, you may do "return modal.exitPromise"